# Update a custom column value sql

Tags: php, mysql, pdo, enums

When outside the boxing thinking. I came up with the following solution:

```
$column = 'product';
$enum = '1';

$product_access = $dbh->prepare("UPDATE products_access SET {$column} = :enum WHERE products_access.id = :id");
$product_accessvar = trim($user['id']);
$product_access->bindParam(':id', $product_accessvar, PDO::PARAM_INT);
$product_access->bindParam(':enum', $enum, PDO::PARAM_INT);
//$product_access->bindParam(':product_enum', $enum);
//foreach($_POST["checkbox2"] as $loc_id) 
$product_access->execute();
```

Thanks for your help, maybe i can help someone with my solution. It works for me now!

---

### Below my question

I have a question about my follow project. I build an sql table where the users can add custom columns with a *enum* value. But the user can also update the value of this column. I can't set any column name because they all custom made by the user, so there is no column name.

My SQL:

```
    tabel `products_access`
--

CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS `products_access` (
  `id` int(30) NOT NULL,
  `user_id` int(30) NOT NULL,
  `product 2` enum('0','1') NOT NULL COMMENT 'Dit is een product beschrijving van product 2.dgfdg'
)
```

Array:

```
Array
(
    [id] => 17
    [name] => product 2
    [number] => 2002
    [description] => Dit is een product beschrijving van product 2.
    [mount] => 34
    [price] => 6778
    [deleted] => 0
    [user_id] => 17
    [product 2] => 1
)
```

Script:

```
<label>
<input name="clickedproduct[]" type="checkbox" value="<?php echo $avlue['id']; ?>" <?php echo (($_SERVER['REQUEST_METHOD'] == 'POST') ? ((isset($_POST[$avlue['name']])) ? ' value="'.$avlue[$avlue['name']].'" checked' : ' value="'.$avlue[$avlue['name']].'"') : (($avlue[$avlue['name']] == '1') ? ' value="'.$avlue[$avlue['name']].'"checked' : ' value="'.$avlue[$avlue['name']].'"')); ?>>
<?php echo $avlue['name']; ?>
</label>
```

PDO:

```
$product_access = $dbh->prepare('UPDATE products_access() VALUES(:id, :loc)');
$product_access->bindValue(':id', $id);
$product_access->bindParam(':loc', $loc_id);
foreach($_POST["checkbox2"] as $loc_id) $product_access->execute();
```

Below the *array* after saving.

```
Array 
( 
       [username] => joshua 
       [rank] => Array 
           ( 
               [0] => 0 
           )

       [koppel] => Array 
             ( 
                 [0] => 1 
             ) 

       [clickedproduct] => Array 
                     ( 
                         [0] => 17 
                     ) 
)
```

Can some one explain the solution?

Comment: There shouldn't be user-defined columns in database.

Comment: Why not? There must be some solutions to edit this.

Comment: I can't help voting down this solution as you're losing the main benefit of PDO: safety of prepared statements.

Comment: How do you mean? This is an solutions to update the data. The way to safety of prepared statements is on the person when he used my solution. This solution is an example of the whole script.

Comment: Your example is insecure because you're adding a variable right in the query instead of preparing it with a placeholder. And there is no way to use a placeholder for a column name. So, it's insecure for anyone.

Comment: I you know another way te no prepare a variable into the query, then i like to hear it from you. Its not the way to success but its an solution on my question to update a custom column.

Answer (score 1):

This sort of application ordinarily is implemented using a metadata table, also known as a key / value store.

Each row of this metadata table identifies

1. the object it describes, with a product_id or similar foreign key.
2. the name of the data item it holds, e.g. 'price' or 'mount'
3. the value of the data item it holds, e,g, '6778' or '34'
4. optionally a code identifying the data type of the item ('money'? 'text'?)

It's easy to add metadata to an object. Insert a row into the metadata table giving the "column name" you want and the value.  It's a little trickier to retrieve it. You need a query, for example, like this.

```
 SELECT p.product_id, a.val as price, b.val as mount
   FROM product p
   LEFT JOIN metadata a ON a.product_id = p.product_id AND a.key='price'
   LEFT JOIN metadata b ON b.product_id = p.product_id AND b.key='mount'
```

WordPress's [wp_postmeta table](https://codex.wordpress.org/Database_Description#Table:_wp_postmeta) setup is a good and widely used example of this data design pattern. It has a [workable API](https://codex.wordpress.org/Metadata_API).

It's ordinarily considered bad practice to use data definition language commands (like `ALTER TABLE CHANGE colname newcolname INT`) in production. For one thing these commands are quite slow and thread-unsafe. For another, when a schema contains all kinds of user-defined columns it's hard to troubleshoot. You're better off using application code, like what I have suggested here, to allow your users to create their own data keys and values.

Comment: Oké, but this isnt wordpress, i can do it on your way but i want an solutions thats works for my way.

Answer (score 0):

- Create a column named 'custom_column' in 'products_access'.(Add user
  defined column name here)
- Create another table named 'tbl_custom_column'
- Add fields 'user_id', 'custom_column_value' (Add your values here)

Hope that will help.

Comment: Is it possible to do it on my way. To change the value of the custom column name ?

Comment: you can use: ALTER TABLE products_access 
ADD custom_column enum('0','1') NOT NULL. But it is not a good idea to use it :)

Comment: Thanks @Ruby But i can't add an column because i need to edit only the value of the column and not the column name.